# How to do I integrate a 304 in Django?

Tags: python, django, header, http-status-code-304

When a user requests the same page, with the same data...I'd like Django to return a 304, so that the browser doesn't have to load the page all over again.

I'm new to this. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's extensive description in Django documentation: [Conditional view processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/conditional-view-processing/)

Following tools are particularly useful:

1. `@last_modified` and `@etag` view decorators.  You supply them with a function to compute the value from request and everything else is done automatically.
2. `django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware` -- it generates required ETag and returns 304 if there's a cache hit, but this still takes server time to generate full HTML and only network time is saved.  Still very good for one-line configuration change.

Answer (score 6):

You could look into Django's [caching system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/), or if you can easily check if the user is requesting the same data, you can return a `HttpResponseNotModified()` - this returns a 304. Check out the docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotModified).

Comment: Server-side caching is useful, but unrelated to HTTP 304. And it's true that you can return HttpResponseNotModified yourself, but  Django already has built-in mechanisms to check for same response and return the 304 for you; see Alex Lebedev's answer.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I didn't know that! I've still got a ton to learn about Django.